# ClassCastException: android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView cannot be cast to com.support.mukhtar.simplekeyboard.CustomKeyboardView android

Tags: android, kotlin, classcastexception

I have SimpleIME.kt class in order to implement simple InputMethodEditor and do my custom keyboard on android:

```
class SimpleIME : InputMethodService(), OnKeyboardActionListener {

private var kv: CustomKeyboardView? = null
private var keyboard: Keyboard? = null
companion object{
    const val TAG :String = "myLogs"
}

private var caps = false

override fun onCreateInputView(): View? {
    kv = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null) as CustomKeyboardView
    keyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty)
    kv!!.keyboard = keyboard
    kv!!.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this)
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateInputView")
    return kv
}
...
}
```

and my CustomKeuboardView class as below:

```
class CustomKeyboardView : KeyboardView {

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

override fun onKeyMultiple(keyCode: Int, repeatCount: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    return super.onKeyMultiple(keyCode, repeatCount, event)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(me: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG,"onTouchEvent "+me.toString())
    return super.onTouchEvent(me)
}
}
```

it throws classCastException as below:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView cannot be cast to com.support.mukhtar.simplekeyboard.CustomKeyboardView
                                                   at com.support.mukhtar.simplekeyboard.SimpleIME.onCreateInputView(SimpleIME.kt:30)
                                                   at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1248)
                                                   at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1669)
                                                   at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1636)
                                                   at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:497)
                                                   at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:202)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if I implement SimpleIME.kt class as follow:

```
class SimpleIME : InputMethodService(), OnKeyboardActionListener {

private var kv: KeyboardView? = null
private var keyboard: Keyboard? = null
companion object{
    const val TAG :String = "myLogs"
}

private var caps = false

override fun onCreateInputView(): View? {
    kv = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null) as KeyboardView
    keyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty)
    kv!!.keyboard = keyboard
    kv!!.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this)
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateInputView")
    return kv
}
...
}
```

it works fine but I need implement onTouchEvent in KeyboardView in order to handle multiple clicks so I think it is necessary to implement CustomKeyboardView Class;
There is an example of CustomKeyboardView written in java: https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard.git
Please help

my question does not same as this: [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785328/java-lang-classcastexception-android-inputmethodservice-keyboardview-cannot-be)

because there is a problem with layout.xml but i do not have any problem with it because it works if i take as KeyboardView as shown before

my layout.keyboard.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#3Aad1a"
android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785328/java-lang-classcastexception-android-inputmethodservice-keyboardview-cannot-be)

Comment: Post your R.layout.keyboard xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` to `CustomKeyboardView` in R.layout.keyboard xml file.

Comment: Thank you very match, i can't vote  you answer don't have enough reputation, Thank you very match

Comment: @MukhtarBimurat if it helps you, please accept  answer - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work